# Basic installation issue for gruntjs - for use with Bootstrap

Tags: ubuntu, twitter-bootstrap-3, gruntjs

Apologies for the vague title - wasn't sure how else to word it.

Basically, I am having problems with grunt. A few weeks ago I installed Bootstrap sourcecode as well as Grunt. Everything was working fine when I ran `grunt`, my LESS compiled to CSS.

I came back to the same installation a few days ago and Grunt was not performing. It isn't even trying to compile any LESS files and I was met with messages about Grunt being missing and/or unmet dependencies (despite my NPM and nodejs being up to date on both my user account and root). I didn't think much to it and decided to reinstall grunt but to no avail.

Right now I have just deleted my bootstrap directory entirely under public_html. I then cloned from Github. I checked the cloned repo and it all looks good, it even includes a folder called 'grunt' with the Gruntfile.js beneath it. I assume this has come from the Git clone, which is very useful but ultimately, it's still not working.

I run `grunt` and am met with...

```
module.js:340
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'coffee-script'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous>(/var/www/andrewtanner.me/public_html/bootstrap/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt.js:16:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

I then run `npm install` to attempt the installation of correct dependencies based on package.json but am met with...

```
npm WARN prefer global grunt-cli@0.1.13 should be installed with -g
npm WARN unmet dependency /var/www/andrewtanner.me/public_html/bootstrap/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/findup-sync requires glob@'~3.2.9' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /var/www/andrewtanner.me/public_html/bootstrap/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/glob,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 3.1.21
npm WARN unmet dependency /var/www/andrewtanner.me/public_html/bootstrap/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/findup-sync requires lodash@'~2.4.1' but will load
```

(I have truncated this to save scrolling)

I am at a total loss here. I am running npm 1.4.6 and nodejs 0.10.26 so I don't know wht Grunt won't run, especially considering I've had it running previously with no problems.

**Update:** I am now working on Ubuntu 14.04 (previously 12.04) and am receiving this message when running `npm install`. The errors above are no longer appearing but the common theme is that Grunt is still not installing/working.

> phantomjs@1.9.7-5 install /var/www/dev.andrewtanner.me/public_html/bootstrap/node_modules/grunt-contrib-qunit/node_modules/grunt-lib-phantomjs/node_modules/phantomjs
>   node install.js
>   sh: 1: node: not found
>   npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
>   npm WARN For further explanations, please read
>   /usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian
>   npm ERR! weird error 127
>   npm ERR! not ok code 0

Why is this being more complicated than it needs to be?

Any help would be much appreciated - thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the very same issue with Ubuntu 14.04 and Bootstrap 3.2.0. In my case the problem has been resolved by installing the node.js compatibility package:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

Afterwards I ran `npm install` again, and it worked.

**NOTE:**

Don't forget to delete the `node_modules` folder before running `npm install` again, as the previously failed install may have left it in an inconsistent state.

I had errors on running `grunt dist` like this:

```
Loading Gruntfile.js...^^^ERROR
Error: Cannot find module 'error/validation'
```

Deleting the `node_modules` folder and running `npm install` again has resolved them.